# Stored procedure - ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_PaymentForm_getAll
as
begin
    begin TRAN

    select * from PaymentForm

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

    SELECT * FROM PaymentForm pf where pf.ID = 1

    if @@error <> 0
    begin
        rollback
        return
    end

    commit
end
```

I call this stored procedure in ADO.NET but ADO.NET get result of first select

```
SELECT * FROM PaymentForm
```

I want get result of second `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM PaymentForm pf where pf.ID = 1
```

Comment: Why do you have a _delay_ in there?

Comment: I use this to test `LOCKS & ISOLATION LEVELS` in local computer

Answer (score 4):

Use [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx)

Comment: With the `Read()` method, like you'd otherwise use. `NextResult()` only advances to the next result set, it doesn't do any actual reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can add:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

at the beginning of your SP to avoid multiple resultset. Alternatively you can browse across the multiple resultset returned ( if needed ) from your SP by using
[reader.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx)